# beginner sql missing keyword and invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00904

```
CREATE table Book
(
book_title varchar (100) not null ,
book_genre char(60) not null,
Date_of_publish date not null,
user_code char(7) not null ,
book_id char (7) primary key not null , 
constraint writer__id_fk foreign key (writer_id),
constraint publisher__id_fk foreign key (publisher_id)

);
```

I'm getting

> [ORA-00905: missing keyword]

in publisher table

```
CREATE table publisher

(
publisher_id char (7) primary key not null,
publisher_name char(20) not null,
publisher_number char(10) not null,
publisher_email varchar2(60) not null,
publisher_address varchar2(60) not null,
);
```

I'm getting

> [ORA-00904: : invalid identifier]

Comment: OK I solved the [ORA-00904: : invalid identifier] problem

Comment: CREATE table Book
(
book_title varchar (100) not null ,
book_genre char(60) not null,
Date_of_publish date not null,
user_code char(7) not null ,
book_id char (7) primary key not null , 
constraint writer__id_fk foreign key REFERENCES writer (writer_id),
constraint publisher__id_fk foreign key REFERENCES publisher (publisher_id)

);  i'm getting a ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis

Comment: All problems solved. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of SQL! :-)

**General remark:**
Please tell us what kind of DBMS you're using. MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? SQlite? Different systems use different kinds of syntaxes.

### **First statement:**

The problem seems to be in the `FOREIGN KEY`-portion.
Usually, you'll state something like:

`CONSTRAINT [constraint_name] FOREIGN KEY([column_in_this_table]) REFERENCES OTHER_TABLE([column_in_other_table])`

*edit (added):*

---

The `[column_in_this_table]` has to exist in your DDL (`CREATE TABLE`-statement), like so:
`CREATE TABLE Book ( book_title ... etc., publisher_id INT, CONSTRAINT FK_publ_id FOREIGN KEY(publisher_id) REFERENCES publisher(publisher_id));`

Here, you'll have a 'original' column called 'publisher_id', in the 'publisher'-table. You refer to it from within the 'Book'-table, by first having a 'publisher_id' column in the 'Book'-table *(which should have the same DDL as the original column by the way)*. Next, you'll add a `FOREIGN KEY` to the 'Book'-table, that is imposed on the Book(publisher_id) column. Note, that you could also name the column in your 'Book'-table differently -- like, say, 'Spongebob' or 'Patrick'. But for future use, you'd like naming conventions that tell what you might expect to find in a column. So you'd name columns for what they contain.

---

### **Second statement:**

The problem is with the last portion of your statement, where there's a **comma** after the `NOT NULL` portion for column `publisher_address`.

(Part of) your statement:

`publisher_address varchar2(60) not null, );`

Try replacing that with:

`publisher_address VARCHAR2(60) NOT NULL);`

---

*edit (note to self):*
`VARCHAR2` turns out to be a valid datatype in Oracle databases (see:
 [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1822))

Comment: Thank you. I am using oracle

Comment: Thanks for that info (pro-tip: add 'oracle' as a tag in your question). Also, what I failed to see earlier: first add a column called 'publisher_id' to your Book table. Then, add a foreign key, on that column. Like so (abbreviated example):

`CREATE TABLE Book ( book_title ... etc.
, publisher_id INT ,
CONSTRAINT FK_publ_id FOREIGN KEY(publisher_id) REFERENCES publisher(publisher_id)
);`

_Alternatively:_
`CREATE TABLE Book ( book_title ... etc.
, publisher_id INT FOREIGN KEY(publisher_id) REFERENCES publisher(publisher_id)
);` but you won't have any control over the CONSTRAINT name.

Comment: Great! Updated my answer to include the additional info. Accepting any of the given answers, as the preferred answer, would be appreciated by any of the answerers also :-)

Answer (score 2):

The following SQL creates a FOREIGN KEY on the "PersonID" column when the "Orders" table is created:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
    OrderID int NOT NULL,
    OrderNumber int NOT NULL,
    PersonID int,
    PRIMARY KEY (OrderID),
    FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID)
    );
```

Refer this link for more details

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For your first table, the Foreign Keys do not reference any table. For your second table, I would imagine that comma after your last column isn't helping anything.

Comment: What is the correct way to refrence a table. I have a table called writer and a table called publisher

Answer (score 0):

So this is the answer.

CREATE table Book
(
book_title varchar (100) not null ,
book_genre char(60) not null,
Date_of_publish date not null,
user_code char(7) not null ,
publisher_id char (7) not null,
writer_id char(7) not null,
book_id char (7) primary key not null , 
 CONSTRAINT book_writer_id_fk FOREIGN KEY(writer_id) REFERENCES writer(writer_id),
 CONSTRAINT book_publisher_id_fk FOREIGN KEY(publisher_id) REFERENCES publisher(publisher_id)
);

CREATE table publisher

(
publisher_id char (7) primary key not null,
publisher_name char(20) not null,
publisher_number char(10) not null,
publisher_email varchar2(60) not null,
publisher_address varchar2(60) not null
);